# python VisibleDeprecationWarning

Tags: python, deep-learning

I encoutered the following error while importing my dataset.

```
from keras.datasets import reuters
(train_data, train_labels),(test_data, test_labels) = reuters.load_data(num_words=10000)
```

```
 VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences 
(which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
  x_test, y_test = np.array(xs[idx:]), np.array(labels[idx:])
```

It would be helpful if someone can suggest a way to overcome/solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

This warning comes from `numpy.array()` function and appears when numpy tries to create array with nested sequences of various length. To invoke the warning you could do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
labels = ['a', 'b', 'c']
xs = [[1, 2], [4], [2, 5, 7]]
(train, test) = (np.array(xs[:2]), np.array(labels[:2]))
```

Then you surely get `VisibleDeprecationWarning` caused by `xs` array. When you would change `xs` to `xs=[[1,2],[4,7],[2,5]]` the warning would disapear. The same situation comes from reuters data - there are many nested arrays but of various lengths. By the way you could do the same like in case of `xs` array by use of `maxlen` parameter for `load_data()` and set it to shortest nested array in reuters data, like this: `reuters.load_data(maxlen=13)`...which is obviously something you don't want to do.

So, the simplest solution is just to switch off the warning, because...hey! It's just a warning :).

```
import warnings
import numpy as np
from keras.datasets import reuters
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=np.VisibleDeprecationWarning)

(train_data, train_labels),(test_data, test_labels) = reuters.load_data(num_words=10000)
```

Another solution would be to modify `reuters.load_data()` function where `dtype=object` is missing in `np.array()` call (eventually you could use `action='error'` in `warnings.simplefilter` - then error is raised instead of warning - run `load_data()` in `try-except` block and call your modified reuters module when error is catched...)

```
# current load_data() definition with problematic part (on end of the function)
x_train, y_train = np.array(xs[:idx]), np.array(labels[:idx])
# should be changed for example into this:
x_train, y_train = np.array(xs[:idx], dtype=object), np.array(labels[:idx], dtype=object)

# or add dtype parametr to load_data() params with None as default value, like this:
def load_data(path='reuters.npz',num_words=None,...,dtype=None,...):
    ...
    x_train, y_train = np.array(xs[:idx], dtype=dtype), np.array(labels[:idx], dtype=dtype)
# and you may set the param from your code whenever you want:
(train_data, train_labels),(test_data, test_labels) = reuters.load_data(num_words=10000, dtype=object)
```

But I suppose that to switch off the warning is sufficient solution